# How to get the list of selected items in naive 0-1 knapsack?

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-science, knapsack-problem

I have a code of the naive solution of the Knapsack problem, i want to get the list of of selected items, currently it is returning the total sum of values of the selected items. Any help will be appreciated. PYTHON CODE:

```
    def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
 
    # Base Case
    if n == 0 or W == 0:
        return 0
 
    # If weight of the nth item is
    # more than Knapsack of capacity W,
    # then this item cannot be included
    # in the optimal solution
    if (wt[n-1] > W):
        return knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1)
 
    # return the maximum of two cases:
    # (1) nth item included
    # (2) not included
    else:
        return max(
            val[n-1] + knapSack(
                W-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1),
            knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1))
 
# end of function knapSack
 
 
#Driver Code
items= [a, b, c, d, e]
val = [60, 100, 120, 125, 129]
wt = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
W = 70
n = len(val)
print knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
```

Comment: I just ran it as is and got 285 as a result.  Are you getting 534 instead? Oh nevermind, sorry I can't read.  I see what you're looking for.  Give me a sec and I'll update in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the trick here is to return both the path of items selected `p` along with the value accrued `v` by choosing that path.  Then you select the best path based on the maximum value `v`.

```py
def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
 
    # Base Case
    if n == 0 or W == 0:
        return 0, []
 
    # If weight of the nth item is
    # more than Knapsack of capacity W,
    # then this item cannot be included
    # in the optimal solution
    if (wt[n-1] > W):
        return knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1)
 
    # return the maximum of two cases:
    # (1) nth item included
    v1, p1 = knapSack(W-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1)
    v1 += val[n-1]
    p1 = [items[n-1]] + p1
    
    # (2) not included
    v2, p2 = knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1)
    
    return (v1, p1) if v1 >= v2 else (v2, p2)
    
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    items = list('abcde')
    val = [60, 100, 120, 125, 129]
    wt = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
    W = 70
    n = len(val)
    val, path = knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
    print(val, path)
```

Note, there are a few additional measures you can use to speed up this code.  The most notable would be adding memoization, then would be converting it to a bottom-up dp solution.  Feel free to drop a comment if you would like to know more about how to apply these.